# How to define an empty Vuex state and then check it is not empty/null in Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store which defines a state as null:

```
const state = {
    Product: null  // I could do Product:[] but that causes a nested array of data
};

const getters = {
     getProduct: (state) => state.Product
};

const actions = {
     loadProduct({commit}, {ProudctID}) {
     axios.get(`/api/${ProductID}`).then(response => {commit('setProduct', response.data)})
     .catch(function (error) {
     //error handler here
     }
   }
};

const mutations = {
     setProduct(state, ProductData) {
     state.Product = ProductData
     }
};
```

In my Vue component I want to display the `Product` data when it is available. So I did this:

```
<template>
   <div v-if="Product.length">{{Product}}</div>
</template>
```

When I run it, I get an error stating

> Vue warn: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length'
>   of null"

Okay, so I tried this which then does nothing at all (throws no errors and never displays the data):

```
<template>
   <div v-if="Product != null && Product.length">{{Product}}</div>
</template>
```

What is the correct way to display the `Product` object data if it is not null? `Product` is a JSON object populated with data from a database which is like this:

`[{ "ProductID": 123, "ProductTitle": "Xbox One X Gaming" }]`

My Vue component gets the data like this:

```
computed:
            {
            Product() {
                return this.$store.getters.getProduct
            }
        }
        ,
        serverPrefetch() {
            return this.getProduct();
        },
        mounted() {
            if (this.Product != null || !this.Product.length) {
                this.getProduct();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getProduct() {
                return this.$store.dispatch('loadProduct')
            }
        }
```

If I look in Vue Dev Tools, it turns out that `Product` in my Vue component is always `null` but in the Vuex tab it is populated with data. Weird?

Comment: the populated `Product` state has a value as `[...]` or `{....}`?

Comment: It would be like `[{ "ProductID": 123, "ProductTitle": "Xbox One X Gaming" }]`

Comment: In your template, just leave it at  
    v-if="this.state.Product != null"

Comment: how are you getting back that state in your component logic?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have updated my post to show how I'm getting it. Upon checking with Vue Dev Tools, it seems my Vue component's computed `Product` data is always null which is probably the cause of the problem. Caught the problem - it should be `mounted() if (this.Product == null ...)` not `!= null`

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case to use computed:

```
computed: {
   product() {
     return this.Product || [];
   }
}
```

Comment: The || [] means that the element will be rendered on the page, even if Product has not been populated with anything. So, I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: This will allow to do `v-if="product.length"` in template

Answer (score 1):

In the store function when you do the request you can check
examoe

```
const actions = {
     loadProduct({commit}, {ProudctID}) {
if (this.product.length > 0) {// <-- new code
  return this.product // <-- new code
} else { // <-- new code
     // do the http request
     axios.get(`/api/${ProductID}`)
    .then(response => {
    commit('setProduct', response.data)}
    )
     .catch(function (error) {
     //error handler here
     }
   }// <-- new code
   }
};
```